# Using articles in english, articles before dates

Tags: grammar, articles

I have been asking by my daughter about which articles shall be used in following sentence, although her teacher has given different explication which i am not 100% convinced.

June the first is Children's Day.

Her teacher insists that the article The should not be used before Children's.

How to make sure that her teacher has given the right answer?

Please help.

Comment: "Children's Day" in this circumstance is a proper noun, which does not take the article, like Christmas and May Day. Oxford: `a name used for an individual person, place, or organization, spelled with initial capital letters, e.g., Larry, Mexico, and Boston Red Sox.`

Comment: [English is capitalized. Also, [which can, could, should be used, not will as will means something definite]

Comment: It would be very odd to put "the" before [Father's Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Father%27s_Day) or similar occasions.  I'm not familiar with [Children's Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children's_Day) but it seems to be a similar thing.

Answer (score 1):

No, the article is placed correctly in the date. First let me explain why it is there, then I'll address why it shouldn't be where you suggest it could go.

Articles in dates, as in your example, are most common in *British* English and less so in US English - but it should be noted that British English speakers usually say the date differently anyway, for example:

- "06/01/2023", pronounced as "*June first*" (US English)
- "01/06/2023", pronounced as "*(The) first of June*" (British English).

In everyday use, the article "the" *can* be optional in the British way of stating the date. However, it isn't incorrect in that dialect to say the date with the name of the month first, and certain notable dates seem to be commonly said that way around. When we do say them that way around, we include the article (eg "*Christmas Day is December **the** 25th*").

"Children's Day" is a *proper noun*, and proper nouns don't usually have articles, which is why it does not belong where you thought it might. For the same reason, my example of "Christmas Day" doesn't have an article, either - it isn't "***the** Christmas Day*". So, as you can see, it has not been incorrectly placed - it belongs in the date and does not belong in front of the noun.

Comment: @user424874 I know, but they are labouring under a misconception which I am addressing first. I'm expanding the answer.